# Deconvolution to extract the latent kernel

Tags: python, scipy, fft, convolution

Suppose  `A * X = B` is a `full-convolution`; therefore, if `matrix A` is N x N and `matrix X` is M x M, `matrix B` must be (N+M-1) x (N+M-1). I do know `A` and `B`, but not `X`; so I would like to find it.

Since deconvolution by Fourier transform wants all involved matrices to be of same size, we pad `A` with zeros to become (N+M-1) x (N+M-1).

This is easily done in Python,

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft2, ifft2

shape = B.shape
X_pre = ifft2(fft2(B, shape) / fft2(A, shape)).real

X = X_pre[:??, :??] # what do I put here to extract the latent kernel X?
```

The problem is that the size of `X_pre` is (N+M-1) x (N+M-1), but I would like to get `X` which is of size M x M. Knowing that `M` is much smaller than `N`, how would I extract the latent kernel `X`?

Thanks in advance...